# Nginx not rendering style

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am working on a simple Wordpress app and testing loadbalance on nginx and docker.
The problem is that the styling of the page is loading on the http website, but not working on the https as you can on the images.

**My docker-compose.yml:**

```
services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx:stable-alpine
        restart: always
        ports: 
            - 80:80
            - 443:443
        volumes:
            - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
            - ./cert/:/etc/nginx/ssl
            - ./nginx-logs:/var/log/nginx
        depends_on:
            - wordpress-1
            - wordpress-2
        networks:
            - wpsite

    wordpress-1:
        build: 
            context: ./wordpress
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        container_name: wordpress-test-1
        ports:
            - 8000:80
        restart: always
        volumes: 
            - ./:/var/www/html:delegated
        environment:
            WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mysql:3306
            WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
            WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
        depends_on:
            - mysql 
        networks:
            - wpsite
    
    wordpress-2:
        build: 
            context: ./wordpress
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        container_name: wordpress-test-2
        ports:
            - 8080:80
        restart: always
        volumes: 
            - ./:/var/www/html:delegated
        environment:
            WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mysql:3306
            WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
            WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - wordpress-1
        networks:
            - wpsite        

    mysql:
        image: mysql:latest
        volumes:
            - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
        restart: always
        environment: 
            MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
            MYSQL_USER: wordpress
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
        networks:
            - wpsite

networks:
    wpsite:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
  db_data:
```

**My Nginx.conf file:**

```
events { 
    worker_connections 1024; 
}

http{

    upstream all {
        server wordpress-1;
        server wordpress-2;
    }    

    server {
        server_name wordpress-docker.test;
        
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;

        ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/wordpress-docker.test+4.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/wordpress-docker.test+4-key.pem;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
        
        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://all;
            proxy_set_header Host            $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP       $proxy_protocol_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_protocol_addr;
        }
    }
}
```

HTTPS result

[image]

HTTP result

[image]

I hope someone can help me with this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could figure it out.

To fix this problem I just had to add "proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;" to nginx.conf file.

```
events { 
    worker_connections 1024; 
}

http{

    upstream all {
        server wordpress-1;
        server wordpress-2;
    }    

    server {
        server_name wordpress-docker.test;
        
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;

        ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/wordpress-docker.test+4.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/wordpress-docker.test+4-key.pem;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
        
        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://all;
            proxy_set_header Host            $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP       $proxy_protocol_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_protocol_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        }
    }
}
```

and in the wp-config.php I just added:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')
 $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';

define('WP_HOME','https://wordpress-docker.test');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://wordpress-docker.test');
```

I hope this can be helpfull.